# Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

«В науке (-) иначе». Стоит ли ставить тире?

Answer (score 1):

В неполных предложениях может ставится тире вместо пропущенного члена предложения. А может и не ставится. На Ваше усмотрение. Послушайте свою интонацию. Есть пауза? Есть тире.

Answer (score 0):

Я, конечно, прошу прощения у сяс... Но с такой грамотностью лучше ответов не давать:((( А тире в предложенной фразе ставить можно.

Answer (score -3):

Конечно если можно было бы не пользоваться тире. Вот ты представь, ты пишеш диктант и у тебя задает вопрос, ставить что: запятую, тире или двоеточие. Проше было если можно было бы просто ставить запятую. Хотя раньше люди и без них справлялись. Но как видеш сейчас грамотные люди использют в диктанттах тире, а в документах ты хоть раз видел, что бы использывали запятые или тире. Я сейчас скоро то же буду писать диктант, чтоб поступить. Это, мне кажется, савсем неудобно поэтоому мой ответ нет.